# I get a different result in my SQL deduction query

Tags: mysql, sql

My query is supposed to return the difference between the order and sales (order-sales). It should get the total order_quantity in inventories_order and the total quantity in sales per product and get the difference between the two to get the remaining.

Example

2. product1: (3+7) - 179 =  -169
3. product2: (150) - (111+30) = 9

Tables:

```
|---------------------------------------------|
|             inventories_order               |
|---------------------------------------------|
|      invent_id      |     order_quantity    |
|---------------------|-----------------------|
|          1          |         3             |
|---------------------|-----------------------|
|          2          |         150           |
|---------------------|-----------------------|
|          1          |         7             |
|---------------------|-----------------------|

|---------------------------------------------|
|                   sales                     |
|---------------------------------------------|
|      invent_id      |     quantity          |
|---------------------|-----------------------|
|          1          |         179           |
|---------------------|-----------------------|
|          2          |         111           |
|---------------------|-----------------------|
|          2          |         30            |
|---------------------|-----------------------|

|---------------------------------------------|
|                 inventories                 |
|---------------------------------------------|
|      invent_id      |     product_name      |
|---------------------|-----------------------|
|          1          |         product1      |
|---------------------|-----------------------|
|          2          |         product2      |
|---------------------|-----------------------|


  String selectQuery = "SELECT product_name, ((sum(IFNULL(o.order_quantity,0))) - ((sum(s.quantity)))"
            + " ) as quantity_left "
            + " FROM inventories i left join inventories_order o on i.invent_id=o.invent_id "
            + " left join sales s on i.invent_id=s.invent_id "
            + " group by i.invent_id order by quantity_left desc ";
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? format instead of image. that really help

Comment: @D-Shih: First of all apologies for the vague question.  I provided additional information to make it clearer. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I add an answer you can try it.  @Roger

Comment: You already had the answer.

Comment: Are there some missing PRIMARY KEYs?

Comment: @CetinBasoz Sorry, I just saw your answer. I just have a question which I posted below your answer as a comment.

Comment: @Strawberry no I haven't included the PRIMARY KEY's as I was merely after the logic of how to SUM up different columns and subtract them.

Comment: It generally aids comprehension if you include the PK

Comment: @Strawberry noted sir. I will keep that in mind for future questions. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: FWIW, and despite the upvotes, I'm not convinced that the accepted solution is the best option on the table.

Comment: @Strawberry Why would you say it's not the best answer? It works fine and it is simple to read, understand and implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have join in your query. When you have join which is not between only parent-child (1-to-many) then SUM result would never be reliable. First do your aggregation:

```
SELECT IFNULL(o.orderQty,0)-ifnull(s.saleQty,0) as quantity_left 
FROM inventories i 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT invent_id, SUM(order_quantity) AS orderQty
 FROM inventories_order
 group by invent_id) o on i.invent_id=o.invent_id
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT invent_id,SUM(quantity) AS saleQty
  FROM sales
  group by invent_id) s on i.invent_id=s.invent_id
ORDER by quantity_left desc
```

Comment: Your answer is nice and I was able to incorporate to my problem. However, instead of getting -169 and 9 I ended up with -170 and 8.  Why is it leaving out 1 number?

Comment: @Roger, probably your data has different values. I get -169 and 9. Here is the link to sqlFiddle sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2679e3/2

Comment: @True, I will check it out. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION ALL` on the `inventories_order` and `sales` table.

1. `grp` column  `1` in `inventories_order` mean positive number.
2. `grp` column  `-1` in `sales` mean negative number.

Use `Outer JOIN` with `inventories`  use `SUM` and simple multiplication to make it.

**TestDLL**

```
CREATE TABLE inventories_order(
  invent_id  INT, 
  order_quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO inventories_order VALUES 
(1,3), (2,150), (1,7);

CREATE TABLE sales(
  invent_id  INT, 
  quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO sales VALUES
(1,179), (2,111), (2,30);

CREATE TABLE inventories(
  invent_id  INT, 
  product_name VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO inventories VALUES (1,'product1'), (2,'product2');
```

**Query**

```
select t1.product_name,IFNULL(sum(num*grp),0) as quantity_left
from 
(
  SELECT 1 grp,order_quantity as num,invent_id FROM inventories_order 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT -1,quantity,invent_id FROM sales   
)t 
RIGHT JOIN inventories t1 on t.invent_id= t1.invent_id
GROUP BY t1.product_name
```

**[Results]**:

```
| product_name | quantity_left |
|--------------|---------------|
|     product1 |          -169 |
|     product2 |             9 |
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/472eea/2)

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well. Much appreciated.